How to change app Icon dynamically with dart language of flutter?
After doing a lot of R&D , I'm able to change app icon dynamically with dart language of flutter.
For achieve this:
At first I was looking for plugin & had found one (flutter_dynamic_icon) but that works only on iOS. But I need to implement for both platforms (android and iOS) so did some R&D again and found a Blog, that actually matched my requirements.  It used method channel for achieve this and I did the same and it worked.
But there is an issue I have discovered , when I tap on function to set app icon the dynamically , app closes itself and shows app icon has been changed but I don't want to app get closed.
NOTE : This is the first I have used method channel to call native asynchronous method and never worked with kotlin language so I'm not able to do that means how to prevent from app getting closed after setting the app icon dynamically.
Code:
Android side :
MainActivity.kt
package com.app.demo



import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

   private val CHANNEL = "com.dynamicIcon"
   var methodChannelResult: MethodChannel.Result? = null


   @Override
   override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
       super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

       MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->

           try {
               methodChannelResult = result;
               if (call.method.equals("launcherFirst")) {                
                   setIcon("launcherAlias.FirstLauncherAlias", 1)
                   result.success(true)
               } else if (call.method.equals("launcherSecond")) {                 
                   setIcon("launcherAlias.SecondLauncherAlias", 2)
                   result.success(true)

               }else if (call.method.equals("launcherThird")) {                 
                   setIcon("launcherAlias.ThirdLauncherAlias", 3)
                   result.success(true)

               }else if (call.method.equals("launcherFourth")) {                 
                   setIcon("launcherAlias.FourthLauncherAlias", 4)
                   result.success(true)

               }else if (call.method.equals("launcherFifth")) {                 
                   setIcon("launcherAlias.FifthLauncherAlias", 5)
                   result.success(true)

               } else {
//                   
                   setIcon("launcherAlias.DefaultLauncherAlias", 0)
                   result.success(true)
               }
           } catch (e: Exception) {
               print(e)
           }
       }
   }


   //dynamically change app icon
   private fun setIcon(targetIcon: String, index: Int) {
       try {
           val packageManager: PackageManager = applicationContext!!.packageManager
           val packageName = applicationContext!!.packageName
           val className = StringBuilder()
           className.append(packageName)
           className.append(".")
           className.append(targetIcon)

           when (index) {
               0 -> {
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(packageName, "$packageName.$targetIcon"),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )

                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName!!,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FirstLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.SecondLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.ThirdLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FourthLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FifthLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
               }

               1 -> {
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(packageName, "$packageName.$targetIcon"),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )

                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName!!,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.DefaultLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName!!,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.SecondLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.ThirdLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FourthLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FifthLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
               }

               2 -> {
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(packageName, "$packageName.$targetIcon"),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )

                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName!!,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.DefaultLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName!!,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FirstLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.ThirdLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FourthLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FifthLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
               }

               3 -> {
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(packageName, "$packageName.$targetIcon"),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )

                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName!!,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.DefaultLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName!!,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FirstLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.SecondLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FourthLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FifthLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
               }

               4 -> {
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(packageName, "$packageName.$targetIcon"),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )

                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName!!,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.DefaultLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName!!,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FirstLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.SecondLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.ThirdLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )

                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FifthLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
               }

               5 -> {
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(packageName, "$packageName.$targetIcon"),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )

                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName!!,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.DefaultLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName!!,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FirstLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.SecondLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.ThirdLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )
                   packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                       ComponentName(
                           packageName,
                           "$packageName.launcherAlias.FourthLauncherAlias"
                       ),
                       PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                       PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
                   )

               }

           }
       } catch (e: Exception) {
           print(e)
       }
   }
}


AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   package="com.app.demo">
   <uses-permission
       android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission
       android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission
       android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
   <application
       android:label="Demo"
       android:name="${applicationName}"
       android:icon="@drawable/black_app_icon">
       <!-- tools:replace="android:icon" -->

       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:exported="true"
           android:enabled="false"
           android:launchMode="singleTop"
           android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
           android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
           <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
           <meta-data
               android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
               android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>

       <activity-alias
           android:name=".launcherAlias.FirstLauncherAlias"
           android:enabled="false"
           android:icon="@drawable/black_app_icon"
           android:label="Demo"

           android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
           android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />


           </intent-filter>
       </activity-alias>


       <activity-alias
           android:name=".launcherAlias.SecondLauncherAlias"
           android:enabled="false"
           android:icon="@drawable/blue_app_icon"
           android:label="Demo"

           android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
           android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />


           </intent-filter>
       </activity-alias>

       <activity-alias
           android:name=".launcherAlias.ThirdLauncherAlias"
           android:enabled="false"
           android:icon="@drawable/red_app_icon"
           android:label="Demo"

           android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
           android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />


           </intent-filter>
       </activity-alias>

       <activity-alias
           android:name=".launcherAlias.FourthLauncherAlias"
           android:enabled="false"
           android:icon="@drawable/yellow_app_icon"
           android:label="Demo"

           android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
           android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />


           </intent-filter>
       </activity-alias>

       <activity-alias
           android:name=".launcherAlias.FifthLauncherAlias"
           android:enabled="false"
           android:icon="@drawable/green_app_icon"
           android:label="Demo"

           android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
           android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />


           </intent-filter>
       </activity-alias>


       <activity-alias
           android:name=".launcherAlias.DefaultLauncherAlias"
           android:enabled="true"
           android:icon="@drawable/white_app_icon"
           android:label="Demo"

           android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
           android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />


           </intent-filter>
       </activity-alias>

       <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
            This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
       <meta-data
           android:name="flutterEmbedding"
           android:value="2"/>

   </application>
</manifest>

Flutter's dart code side:
dynamic_launcher.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class DynamicLauncher extends StatefulWidget {
 const DynamicLauncher({super.key});

 @override
 State<DynamicLauncher> createState() => _DynamicLauncherState();
}

class _DynamicLauncherState extends State<DynamicLauncher> {
static const platform = MethodChannel('com.dynamicIcon');

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
       title: const Text('Dynamic Launcher Icons'),
     ),
     body: Column(
       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: [
         const Text('Change Launcher Icon'),
         const SizedBox(height: 50),
         TextButton.icon(
           onPressed: () async {
             try{
               var result =  await platform.invokeMethod('launcherFirst');
               debugPrint("Set Green AppIcon Success :$result");
             }catch(e){
               debugPrint("Set Black AppIcon Failed :${e.toString()}");
             }
           },
           icon: const Icon(
             Icons.android,
             color: Colors.black,
           ),
           label: const Text(
             'Set Black AppIcon',
             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
           ),
         ),
         TextButton.icon(
           onPressed: () async {

             try{
               var result =   await platform.invokeMethod('launcherSecond');
               debugPrint("Set Blue AppIcon Success:$result");
             }catch(e){
               debugPrint("Set Blue AppIcon Failed :${e.toString()}");
             }
           },
           icon: const Icon(
             Icons.android,
             color: Colors.blue,
           ),
           label: const Text(
             'Set Blue AppIcon',
             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
           ),
         ),
         TextButton.icon(
           onPressed: () async {

             try{
               var result =   await platform.invokeMethod('launcherThird');
               debugPrint("Set Red AppIcon Success:$result");
             }catch(e){
               debugPrint("Set Red AppIcon Failed :${e.toString()}");
             }
           },
           icon: const Icon(
             Icons.android,
             color: Colors.red,
           ),
           label: const Text(
             'Set Red AppIcon',
             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
           ),
         ),
         TextButton.icon(
           onPressed: () async {

             try{
               var result =   await platform.invokeMethod('launcherFourth');
               debugPrint("Set Yellow AppIcon Success:$result");
             }catch(e){
               debugPrint("Set Yellow AppIcon Failed :${e.toString()}");
             }
           },
           icon: const Icon(
             Icons.android,
             color: Colors.yellow,
           ),
           label: const Text(
             'Set Yellow AppIcon',
             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),
           ),
         ),
         TextButton.icon(
           onPressed: () async {

             try{
               var result =   await platform.invokeMethod('launcherFifth');
               debugPrint("Set Green AppIcon Success:$result");
             }catch(e){
               debugPrint("Set Green AppIcon Failed :${e.toString()}");
             }
           },
           icon: const Icon(
             Icons.android,
             color: Colors.green,
           ),
           label: const Text(
             'Set Green AppIcon',
             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
           ),
         ),
         TextButton.icon(
           onPressed: () async {

             try{
               var result =   await platform.invokeMethod('default');
               debugPrint("Set Default appIcon Success :$result");
             }catch(e){
               debugPrint("Set Default appIcon Failed :${e.toString()}");
             }
           },
           icon: const Icon(
             Icons.restore,
             color: Colors.grey,
           ),
           label: const Text(
             'Set Default App Icon',
             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
           ),
         ),


       ],
     ),
   );
 }
}


Look at this video that I want to achieve : reference
Result that I'm getting :  output_Video

You could try to save the aliases to be enabled/disabled in memory and actually enable/disable them with setComponentEnabledSetting inside onPause or onDestroy.

How do I do? can you please attach some piece of code?? That would be easier to understand because I said earlier I'm not familiar with Kotlin language

Do you get any output in the debug window when it crashes

@Thomas please check Videos That I have attached , then you will find what I have done and I wan to achieve.

I understand what you want to achive. do you get any output in the debug pane of your debugger when that happens
